# find a Telegram channel members count without any libraries in php

Tags: php, telegram

I am trying to find a Telegram channel members count without any libraries in php.

When we open this link we can see the count:
`https://t.me/{telegram channel id}/`
Is it possible to extract the count with file_get_contents function?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is "yes, it is possible":

```
$html = file_get_contents('https://t.me/CHANNEL_NAME');

preg_match_all('#(.*?) members, (.*?) online#', $html, $matches);

$members = (int) filter_var($matches[1][0], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
$online  = (int) filter_var($matches[2][0], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
```

However, this way is unreliable: telegram devs may change their HTML structure and this answer become out-of-date.

Comment: yes you are wright, but working with telegram api is very hard for me, Has Telegram any way for find channel members count using php?

Comment: `$matches` is a variable that stores results (matches) from RegExp. I suggest you visit [php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) with such questions. And I have no idea why do you ask me again about the same problem when I posted a solution here.